# Get day & date string using DateFormat class - Android

Tags: java, android, date, android-fragments, date-format

I have been reading through all the posts for how to apply getting a day and date in my project, but haven't been able to figure it out (very new to Java).

I have a button with a timestamp on it, but I must convert this timestamp into a day of the week, with date. For example like this: Tuesday, Jan. 4th, 2014.

The date should be the current date when the user clicks the button. **It was recommended that we use the DateFormat class (not currently using it in my fragment file yet), so consider that in an answer.**

However, I have most of my code already written, so it must fit in well with everything, so I can't deconstruct too much. Any ideas for this challenge? I already changed the Crime.java file method to DateFormat (it was just using Date class before), but the other main fragment file will need to use that info, just not sure how to do it.

**Here is my main fragment file I'm building the time code in (time portion of it):**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

mDateButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_date);
        mDateButton.setText(mCrime.getDate().toString());
        mDateButton.setEnabled(false);

}
```

It is in the middle line of code that something needs to change. Currently it brings up a timestamp, but I don't know why (it must be the default of getDate() called on the Date class?)

**Here is my separate Crime class file, with all my instances (whole file):**

```
 public class Crime {

        private UUID mId;
        private String mTitle;
        private DateFormat mDate;
        private boolean mSolved;

        public Crime() {
            //Generate unique identifier
            mId = UUID.randomUUID();
            mDate = new DateFormat();
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return mTitle;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            mTitle = title;
        }

        public UUID getId() {
            return mId;
        }

        public DateFormat getDate() {
            return mDate;
        }

        public void setDate(DateFormat date) {
            mDate = date;
        }

        public boolean isSolved() {
            return mSolved;
        }

        public void setSolved(boolean solved) {
            mSolved = solved;
        }


    }
```

Comment: In Crime.java do you see an `import` statement for `DateFormat` - something like - `import java.text.DateFormat;` ?

Comment: yes, it is imported okay: `import android.text.format.DateFormat;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are stuck with DateFormat, it does not seem to be as flexible as SimpleDateFormat option. Still, you can use it to suit your cause like below:

**Assumption:**
You are using

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
```

**Your modified code:**

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     mDateButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_date);
     mCrime.setDate(DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL));
     mDateButton.setText(mCrime.getDate().format(new Date()));
     mDateButton.setEnabled(false);
...
```

**EDIT:**
Since, your `DataFormat` is of type `android.text.format.DateFormat` change your code to following:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     mDateButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_date);
     mDateButton.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("EEEE, MMM dd yyyy", new java.util.Date()));
     mDateButton.setEnabled(false);
...
```

Comment: Thanks Popo, this seem closer to my original code fore sure! I tried to put it in but got 2 errors. 1 with "FULL" saying it cannot be resolved as a field, and one with "format" saying:

"The method format(CharSequence, long) in the type DateFormat is not applicable for the arguments (Date)"

I imported DateFormat just fine and also changed all the Date classes in my Crime.java to DateFormat okay (no errors).

Not sure if this has anything to do with my version build, but I'm using API 8.

Comment: Ah yes, I changed it and it got rid of the format error!! But I still have the .FULL error.

Comment: Popo, why did that import make a difference and why didn't it automatically import itself?

Comment: @NoniA. Nevermind, I got my answer from your earlier comment. Just change the import to whatever it was before (`android.text.format.DateFormat`) and look at the above edit, use the  changed code

Comment: Okay, now getting 2 errors on `format`: - The static method format(CharSequence, Date) from the type DateFormat should be accessed in a static way, - The method format(Date) in the type DateFormat is not applicable for the arguments (String, Date)

Comment: @NoniA. Okay, these latest errors are after you reverted to your original Crime.java (it should be exactly as it was before)?

Comment: Popo!! I went and changed something in Crime, then put it back and imported and saved everything, and it's now got rid of one of the errors, the main red one, the 2nd one (above). Now it has the yellow error (1st one above) and I ran it just see and the day and month show, but the day and year show as DD YYYY still. So the button now says, "Friday, Jan DD YYYY"... almost there!

Comment: Yes the errors were after I went back to the android import version. But now looks like only the yellow one is there!

Comment: @NoniA. oops, change DD YYYY to `dd yyyy` and yellow one is just a warning! To get rid of the warning see the edit above in `(mDateButton.setText(...)`

Comment: SUCCESS!!! Thanks a million Popo. May I ask one question though, what is the series there of naming with all those dots, `android.text.format.DateFormat.format()` and why create a `new java.util.Date()` ? I'm such a beginner, these are foreign to me.

Comment: @NoniA. Yay!! sure, there are a plenty DateFormatters available as you've seen in all the answers here; since you are using a specific android version of it, to avoid conflicts with others we use a fully qualified name (with all those dots). `Date` class is native to Java and a new instance (`new Date()`) would always define the current time. More details here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Comment: Thanks Popo! :) Ahh, so you are saying using the full name (from the API package it comes from) helps Eclipse to better distinguish from other API versions? Although in my project when I set it up, it was set for API 8 and higher... not just 8. So will it still work on higher than 8?

Comment: @NoniA. Yes and I guess yes :)

Answer (score 2):

I think so you are getting confused with Date format,

From Java Docs

> [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) is an abstract class for date/time formatting subclasses
>   which formats and parses dates or time in a language-independent
>   manner. The date/time formatting subclass, such as SimpleDateFormat,
>   allows for formatting (i.e., date -> text), parsing (text -> date),
>   and normalization. The date is represented as a Date object or as the
>   milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

You need to define `DateFormat` pattern like in my case it is `dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss`, example :

```
private static ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> simpleDateFormatPool = new ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>(){
        protected SimpleDateFormat initialValue() {
            return new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        };
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = null;
        if(dateFormat == null){
            dateFormat = simpleDateFormatPool.get();
        }
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));
    }
```

### OUTPUT

```
Friday 10-Jan-2014 10:41:19
```

Comment: Thanks Prateek, although this code uses classes I know nothing about and I have so many questions about things, I don't think I can understand it enough to use it. Plus in our book it was recommended to use DateFormat, so I have to find a way to do that. Unfortunately the definition of DateFormat sounds like a foreign language to me at this point.

I sort of understand that I do need to define the date format in some way, like your example of "EEEE dd-MMM-yyyy" to get the result I want, but not sure how to simply and efficiently do that w/o using all these other classes.

Comment: @NoniA. No need to get confused,DateFormat is simply used to get the date in a format we desired.

Comment: Thanks Prateek :) now if only I can use that knowledge in my code! I have to find a way to change very little and use what I have, but will keep trying.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
Date d1 =new Date();
SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMM'.', dd'th', yyyy");
System.out.println(date.format(d1));

OUTPUT:   
 Tuesday, Jan. 4th, 2014.
```

Comment: Thanks Kaustubh, it seems nice and simple, but I can't find a way to fit it into my existing code. I already have a date variable in my Crime.java file, and if I change that I don't know what consequences it will have. I have to find a way to fit code into this one line:  `mDateButton.setText(mCrime.getDate().toString());` since that is where the timestamp is currently. The mDateButton is where the new date will go, so I have to preserve the functionality of that line somehow. I can't use `System.out.printlin();` either since the code must go on that button.

Comment: ok, i got one solution. replace following line it will not affect your code. 

mDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMM'.', dd'th', yyyy");
// SimpleDateFormat is subclass of DateFormat

mDateButton.setText(mCrime.getDate().formate(new Date()));

Comment: @NoniA. Instead of `d1` or creating a new variable you could use use `mCrime.getDate()`. That's what I did.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it as:

```
String formattedDate = null;

long timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                        "EEEE, MMM, dd, yyyy");
formattedDate = dateFormat.format(cal1.getTime());
```

This will give you output: `Friday, Jan, 10, 2014`

Hope this gives some idea.

Comment: Hi Mystic, thanks.. I tried to put in the code in my `onCreateView()` method, and put the variable at the top, and I didn't get any errors, but then I ran it and my button is now blank, with nothing on it. :( Any idea why?

Comment: Thanks Mystic, I realized that the DateFormat class was not included in your code, so unfortunately I have to try another way to use that class. Is there any way that you see to use that class in my existing code as much as possible, without changing the code structure too much (adding new classes and variables, etc)? It's okay if you can't see a way. Thanks just the same.