# How to convert String into DateFormat in java?

Tags: java

I am working on Java. I have a `String` and I want to convert it into `Date` Format. Please see the lines of code for more details.

```
String dateString = "4:16:06 PM";
```

I want to convert it into the below `Date`:

```
 Date convertedDate  = 2014-04-22 16:16:06.00
```

How can I do this?

Comment: try with [simpledateformat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: try this [get-day-date-string-using-dateformat-class-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036410/get-day-date-string-using-dateformat-class-android/21037173#21037173)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
// get current date
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String a = dateFormat1.format(new Date());

// add current date to your time string
String dateString = a + " 4:16:06 PM";

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss a");
try {
    // parse it. This is you date object.
    Date d = dateFormat2.parse(dateString);
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for following:

```
    DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm:ss a");
    DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS");

    String dateString = "4:16:06 PM";

    Date date;
    try {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        date = df1.parse(dateString);
        cal.setTime(date);

        // Reset year, month, day to current state
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cal2.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        Date convertedDate = cal.getTime();
        System.out.println(df2.format(convertedDate));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
String str_date="13-09-2011";
DateFormat formatter ; 
Date date ; 
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
date = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date); 
System.out.println("Date " +date.getTime());
```

Comment: Op's dateString(input) is a time in PM(12 hour clock) and he want the output as current date + time converted in 24 hour clock .Does your answer do this way?

Comment: An answer should contain more than just a block of code, adding "try this ," does not explain why your code provides a solution.

Comment: @David but if we take more time to explain our answer anybody else will answer and his answer will be accepted.Secondly if OP doesn't understand anything from our try this block we can explain them in our comments.

Comment: @TruePS: What I was expressing was a StackOverflow policy, not my personal opinion. There are rare exceptions, for example if the code contains explanations in the comments, but in this format the question is quite unacceptable.

To explain, SO is not meant as a place to answer an individual's questions, but general questions which are still useful for future users.

Comment: @David I completely understand what you are saying but you gotta agree with me when I say normally users get what they want in 2-3 minutes and accept that answer even if we write comments in our code it takes some time and by taking more time to answer question it is difficult to gain reputation.

Comment: @TruePS: In that case you should change the way you attempt to earn reputation, quick fire answers are **not** the way. For this very reasons a question asker has to wait 15 minutes.

Comment: @David but question askers never waits for 15 minutes,that is the problem.So firstly question askers need to change.

Comment: @TruePS: They have no choice... they can not accept before that: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-post

Comment: @David I couldn't agree with you more  we all know there are rules but the question is if question asker won't follow the rule then how would persons posting answers be encouraged to follow rules.Rules should be equal for everyone

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public class DateClass
 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
String target = "4:16:06 PM";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateFormat dff = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date d=new Date();
String abc="4:16:06 PM";
Date result =  new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm:ss a").parse(abc);  

  System.out.println("The result is "+df.format(d)+" "+dff.format(result));
 }
   }
```

**Feel free to ask anything if you don't understand it and plz respond did it work or not?**